# VB.NET - Auto fill Rich Text Box in WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, browser

**Hi everyone.**

I'm trying to make my program auto fill a form in my WebBrowser. But the HTML code looks like this:

```
<body contenteditable="true" class="forum" spellcheck="true" style="height: auto;">
text is here!
<br></body>
```

How would I make it input text here? Thanks.

Comment: Access the DOM of the document and set the InnerHTML property of the `body` element.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your answer. Could you maybe give an example on how this could be done?